# Does Realm (Net Xamarin) always return a new class instance?

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm

I created a very simple project with nested models User->Coach->Lesson
When I try to get the Lesson instance from path User.CurrentCoach.CurrentLesson I always get a new instance of class Lesson.

For example:

```
 var obj1 = App.CurrentUser.CurrentCoach.CurrentLesson;
 App.Realm.Write(() => App.CurrentUser.CurrentCoach.CurrentLesson.Name = "Second");
 var obj2 = App.CurrentUser.CurrentCoach.CurrentLesson;
```

Here obj1 guid not same as obj2 guid.
Does Realm always return a new instance ? And how to prevent this ?

Models :

```
    public class User : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Coach CurrentCoach { get; set; }
}

public class Coach : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Lesson CurrentLesson { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid guid;
    public Lesson()
    {
        guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code behind `App.CurrentUser.CurrentCoach.CurrentLesson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you access a property, you'll get a new instance. This behavior is by design and there is no way to prevent it. As a rule of thumb, you should not rely on non-persisted properties/fields to be retained in your models. If you want your `guid` field to not change every time you access your property, you should persist it in the database.